# TeamCity: Running FxCop After Build

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-5.0

I think I'm missing a valuable piece of understanding with TeamCity 5.0. Why is there a separate build runner for FxCop? I prefer that my build server run everything, at once (compile, run unit tests, FxCop, etc). The problem is, I don't see how to add more than a single Build Runner for a specific project, so it seems I have to add a second project to TeamCity with a dependency on another project that uses the sln2008 build runner, or I could simply go the long route and build everything out in MSBuild. Am I missing something that should be obvious? Is it possible to configure the sln2008 Build Runner to include FxCop code analysis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think most of the users want their builds with tests to be as fast as possible. Other things like coverage, code analysis, metrics most likely should not be run often. It is enough to run them once per day, because their value is statistics gathered over time.

As for multiple build runners per build configuraution feature - it is one of the most voted in our tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-3660?query=multiple+build+runners, it has very good chances to be implemented in the next versions.